# HTML between extension tags

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Lets say I have an extension in Jinja. I want the extension to have the form:

```
{% start %}
    <h1>{{ something }}</h1>
    <p>{{ something.else }}</p>
    {% for content in lst %}
        <h3>{{ i.name }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% end %}
```

In my extension, I want to have access to the raw text between start and end, so this:

```
<h1>{{ something }}</h1>
<p>{{ something.else }}</p>
{% for content in lst %}
    <h3>{{ i.name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

I would like that in my extension. How could I do that? I have poured over the jinja documentation to no avail.

Comment: You mean the non processed text? like, literally `'{{something}}'` or the value of `something`? Also, do you want to access this from python code?

Comment: Yes to both. I want `"{{something}}"` not the value of `something`. And I need it in python code.

Answer (score 0):

If your desire output is {{something}}, then you can use "raw" block in jinja.

```
{% raw %}
<h1>{{ something }}</h1>
{% endraw %}
```

It will print "{{something}}" (with curly braces).